# Add two json files in one with the same files

Tags: json, go

I have this version of my code: What i need it to change some part of code or just help me, because I checked all links in google.

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("firstfile.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    data1, err := ioutil.ReadFile("secondfile.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
var migrations map[string]interface{}
var migrations1 map[string]interface{}

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &migrations)
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data1), &migrations1)

if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error:", err)
}
//fmt.Println(migrations)
//fmt.Println(migrations1)

mig := migrations["date"]
mig1 := migrations1["date"]

layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
str := fmt.Sprint(mig)
str1 := fmt.Sprint(mig1)
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
t1, err := time.Parse(layout, str1)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
//fmt.Println(t, t1)
firsthour := t.Hour()
secondhour := t1.Hour()

if firsthour == secondhour {
    result := []map[string]interface{}{}

    migrations3 := make(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range migrations {
        if _, ok := migrations[k]; ok {
            migrations3[k] = v
        }
    }

    for k, v := range migrations1 {
        if _, ok := migrations1[k]; ok {
            migrations3[k] = v
        }
    }

    result = append(result, migrations, migrations1)
    fmt.Println(result)
    b, err := json.Marshal(result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(b)

} else {
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &migrations)
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data1), &migrations1)
    fmt.Println(migrations, migrations)
}
```

}

And in the end I got:

```
[{"data":"is nice",
  "date":"2012-04-23T18:24:59.511Z",
  "name":"Kate"},
 {"data":"is a good person",
  "date":"2012-04-23T18:25:00.511Z",
  "name":"Gleison"}]
```

But what I want to get:

```
{
    "name":["kate","gleison"],
    "date":"2012-04-23T18:00:00.000Z",
    "data":["is nice","is a good person"]
}
```

Can you help me to change some parts of my code to fix it?

My 2 json files:

```
 {
        "name":"Kate",
        "date":"2012-04-23T18:24:59.511Z",
        "data":"is nice"
    },
 {
    "name":"Gleison",
    "date":"2012-04-23T18:25:00.511Z",
    "data":"is a good person"
}
```

Comment: this question is incomplete, kindly show the inputs as well.

Comment: How is `date` resolved? The example value does not match either of the two source dates.

Comment: @anand i changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a part of json files GOLANG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411353/change-a-part-of-json-files-golang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
migrations, migrations1 := make(map[string]interface{}), make(map[string]interface{})

data := `{ "name":"Kate", "date":"2012-04-23T18:24:59.511Z", "data":"is nice" }`
data1 := `{ "name":"Gleison", "date":"2012-04-23T18:25:00.511Z", "data":"is a good person" }`

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &migrations)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data1), &migrations1)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"

t, err := time.Parse(layout, fmt.Sprint(migrations["date"]))
t1, err := time.Parse(layout, fmt.Sprint(migrations1["date"]))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

firsthour := t.Hour()
secondhour := t1.Hour()

if firsthour == secondhour {
    result := make(map[string][]interface{})

    for k, v := range migrations {
        result[k] = append(result[k], v)
    }

    for k, v := range migrations1 {
        result[k] = append(result[k], v)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)

    b, err := json.Marshal(result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(b)

} else {
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &migrations)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data1), &migrations1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(migrations, migrations)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me!